# Share dataframe in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-multiprocessing, netcdf

I'm trying to add new value to a dataframe in parallel work.

```
mgr = mp.Manager()
ns = mgr.Namespace()
ns.df = pd.read_csv('testfile.csv')


def main(q):
  file=datalist(q)
  nc=nc4.Dataset(file,'r')# This is the process of reading some data.

  def dosth(）:#process the data, get the result to add
   ####
  return a

  a=dosth(nc)

  ns.df[x,'y']=a

if __name__ == '__main__':

    l2 = np.arange(len(datalist))
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=10)
    pool.map(main,l2)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    ns.df.to_excel('result_t.xlsx')
```

I tried the code above. But I still can't get the result processed by my own function.

Where is my problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: ns.df[x,'y']=a : What is this corresponding to ? It's written after the return, so it won't be executed

Comment: Thank you for your comments, the return inside main() is from the function' dosth()', which will process the data and get the result which will be written in the dataframe.

Comment: I re-wrote my sample code.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use to apply functions on a data-frame in parallel;

```
import multiprocessing

def apply_parallel(df, func, args={}):
    """ Multiprocessing apply for Dataframe """
    cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    if args: func = partial(func, **args)

    df_split = numpy.array_split(df, cores)

    with multiprocessing.Pool(cores) as pool:
        results = pool.map(func, df_split)
        try:
            df = pandas.concat(results)
        except ValueError:
            # result could be a list of Nones
            pass 
    return df
```

Comment: Thank you. But when I add value to the dataframe, I need to confirm some information inside the data to get the location. It is a good code. But it is not suitable for me.